# Yii2 save image to database as base64

Tags: php, file, file-upload, yii2

I am trying to save image as a base64 into database. But when I submit form I am getting the image NULL. I couldn't understand what's wrong.

## VIEW:

```
<div class="content">
                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'products-add-form',
                    'action' => ['products/product-add-form'],
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'options' => [
                        'class' => 'products-tbl-style',
                        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                    ]
                ]); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'productName'); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'cost'); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'available')->dropDownList(['Y' => 'Yes', 'N' => 'No']); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput(['class'=>'btn btn-primary']); ?>
                <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-success products-save-btn']); ?>
                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            </div>
```

## Controller:

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
    var_dump($file->name);
    var_dump($file);
    var_dump($_FILES);
}
```

## Model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['productName', 'cost', 'available', 'image'], 'required'],
            [['cost'], 'number'],
            [['available'], 'string', 'max' => 1],
            [['image'], 'string'],
            [['productName'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
        ];
    }
```

Here my JQuery code, I am submitting the form data via ajax, does it cause a problem?

## JS:

```
$("form#products-add-form").on('beforeSubmit', function(e){
    var form = $(this);
    $.post(
        form.attr('action'),
        form.serialize()
        )
        .done(function(result){
            if(result == 1){
                form.trigger("reset");
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#products-table'});
                $.notify({
                    icon: "pe-7s-check",
                    message: "New product is added"

                },{
                    type: type[2],
                    timer: 10,
                    placement: {
                        from: 'top',
                        align: 'right'
                    }
                });

            }
            else {
                alert(result);
            }
        }).fail(function(){
        console.log("server error");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You shoud use `file` validator, not `string`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send files via AJAX you shoud use `FormData`. To construct a `FormData` object that contains the data from an existing `<form>`, specify that form element when creating the FormData object:

```
$("form#products-add-form").on('beforeSubmit', function(e){
    $.post(
        form.attr('action'),
        new FormData(this) /* this is a form object */
    )
    /* your other code here */
});
```

UPD: As TS mentioned it should be processData set to false. It's impossible to set it for $.post, so we need to use $.ajax

Comment: Thanks for response but I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation". After posting I am using as following :
            `$tmpfile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $tmpfile_contents = file_get_contents($tmpfile->tempName);
            $base64 = base64_encode($tmpfile_contents);`

Comment: And again I am getting empty value for file input value. If send without ajax post, everything is fine I am getting file input values. What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried following :

```
$.ajax( {
      url: 'http://host.com/action/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: new FormData( this ),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    } );
    e.preventDefault();
```

And now it's working, as @SiZE wrote, we need to send file input with FormData() via ajax.

Comment: Yep, processData should be false =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [FileInput](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput) widget it work's perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @imRch, but again I am getting NULL value. I have tried all step-by-step tutorials but no result. And also I am sending form data ( file input also ) via ajax. Can it cause a problem? Thanks!

Comment: I found also this ( http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/54944-cant-upload-image-by-using-kartiks-fileinput-in-yii20/page__gopid__295551#entry295551 ) similar question but no solution, please share if you have a solution for this issue. Thanks!